# Plotly chart is not displayed in jupyiter notebook but in the PyCharm

Tags: python, charts

how to install Plotly 5.1.0 properly to Pycharm using pip to get the chart on jupyter notebook and Pycharm. As a beginner to python, I tried several ways but getting the chart only in the Pycharm but not in jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this finds you well.

First thing I do when installing a package is search [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/plotly/) for the package I am looking for, in your case you would find `pip install plotly` as the install command (you already knew this it seems, but I want to make sure new folks to the thread have this context!)

Second, we can execute terminal/command line commands using an [exclamation point](https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023858254-Executing-Terminal-Commands-in-Jupyter-Notebooks#:%7E:text=In%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20you%20can,you%20are%20trying%20to%20use) in front like `!pip install plotly`

Then this is [what pip command looks like if it downloads successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

Now this either works and you are done, **or it doesn't because the default that `pip` is using is a different directory then the one you are importing to. This happens when there are multiple versions of Python on a computer**

I would follow this [awesome thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip) for more details on it, but you would typically resolve this issue.

Step one: Check where `pip install` is directed to install the package using [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

Step two: Since the Jupyter Notebook installation (from my limited understanding) is its own environment you can use "/where/Jupyter_notebook/is/located -m pip install [package]".

[use sys to path pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVmE4.png)

Pycharm is a bit less technical. You can go to **tools window> Python packages>search 'ploty'> click install on the upper right corner of the screen**

I hope that the above helps you out. This is a pretty tricky concept (I think that this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJvnUQrPluE does a good job of going over what "should" happen)